# Show two Google Analytics API queries in one table

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I want to show both raw data and segmented data in the same table. I currently have a table showing the number of all monthly website users and another table showing the number of users in a segment.

This is the code I have so far:

```
 var allUsers = new gapi.analytics.googleCharts.DataChart({
    reportType: 'ga',
    query: {
        ids: "ga:00000000",
        'dimensions': 'ga:yearmonth',
        'metrics': 'ga:users',
        'start-date': '2014-01-01',
        'end-date': 'today'
    },
    chart: {
        type: 'TABLE',
        container: 'allUsers'
    }
});
allUsers.execute();

var segUsers = new gapi.analytics.googleCharts.DataChart({
    reportType: 'ga',
    query: {
        ids: "ga:00000000",
        dimensions: 'ga:yearmonth',
        metrics: 'ga:users',
        segment: 'gaid::oXNLCnFfS_m-eHpdFg4XOa',
        'start-date': '2014-01-01',
        'end-date': 'today'
    },
    chart: {
        type: 'TABLE',
        container: 'segUsers'
    }
});
segUsers.execute();
```

I would like to combine the data from both tables into one table like this:

```
------------------------------------------------
| YearMonth | Users           | Seg. users     |
------------------------------------------------
| 201401    | 20,123          | 11,345         |
------------------------------------------------
| 201402    | 23,543          | 15,002         |
------------------------------------------------
| 201403    | 12,114          | 14,110         |
------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: I do not quite understand why you want to do this - won't the result be the same as the un-segmented data (of which the segmented data is a part) ?

Comment: The number of users in the segmented data will be smaller.

Comment: Not after you have combined it with the unsegmented data. I simply do not understand how to you expect the combined table to look.

Comment: I've included a table to show what I meant.